Why does after(1000) help to zoom a canvas after deiconify correctly, but after_idle() not?
I have a big tkinter application, where I work with several "withdrawn" tk.toplevels.
An event triggers the following steps:

A withdrawn toplevel is deiconifyed (to make it visible).
The toplevel is lifted (to show it over other windows).
A canvas.bbox("all") command is used to get the size of all the actual visible objects in a canvas of the toplevel.
By using the bbox rectangle and the actual window size a zoom factor is calculated, in order to show all objects in the canvas as big as possible.
Then a canvas.scale command is used for a zoom.

The result is that all objects are visible, but only in a very small size in the upper left corner of the canvas. When the event happens, when the toplevel is already visible, everything is fine.
The solution I am using to solve the problem, is using canvas.after(1000) after deiconify and lift.
But I have 3 questions:

Why does canvas.after_idle() not help in this situation?
Is the canvas the right widget to place the after-command at?
Is there any better solution?


.update_idletasks() is generally all you need to do between changing the state of something, and then doing something that requires accurate dimensions.  (It doesn't matter what widget you invoke this on, or methods like .after().)
